# select2: items added programatically have no text

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

No matter how I try to add items programatically to a select2 (pillbox style) they will only end up having that X for removing them from the list, and no text at the right. Here's an example:

```
var $newOption = $("<option selected='selected'></option>").val("TheID").text("The text")
 
$("#myMultipleSelect2").append($newOption).trigger('change');
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tested this but didn't find any problem with your code. $newOption was added to the options list.

Comment: I found the problem, it was in my "templateSelection" function which was rendering (returning) an empty text for all items.